# Can any explain how this command works?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

When I redirecting the stdin to tee command with argument it displays the string twice.

```
$ echo who is this | tee -
who is this
who is this
```

Comment: If you know what echo does and you know what tee does then this shouldn't even be a question.

Comment: Echo command is used to print the string and tee command is used to redirect the stdin...Here my question is why the echo command displaying the string twice when I added the "-" with tee.

Comment: SO is for computer programming questions, not general questions about using computers. unix.stackexchange.com or superuser.com are better places for questions like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `tee`'s manpage says

> Copy standard input to each FILE, and also to standard output.

Right, so it takes the standard input, which is `who is this\n` and copies it to the standard output. This will make `who is this\n` visible on your terminal once. Additionally, it will also copy the input to the file called `-`. On BSD, that would create a file called `-` and copy the input in there. GNU tee however interprets `-` as standard output which is a somewhat common thing to do. Therefore, it'll copy it to standard output again.

A version that works on BSD an Linux is

```
$ echo who is this | tee /dev/stdout
who is this
who is this
```

You could also make it print the string four times:

```
$ echo who is this | tee /dev/stdout /dev/stdout /dev/stdout  # on Linux alternatively: tee - - -
who is this
who is this
who is this
who is this
```

Comment: Using `-` to mean standard input or output is a common convention of many programs.

Comment: Indeed, as I wrote. But it can be ambiguous at times and I wasn't sure whether OP was aware so explained it.

Answer (score 0):

tee is use to redirect it's input to file & print it on stdout at the same time.